# Showing that two segments in a right triangle are perpendicular

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am working on the following problem:

> In a right triangle $ABC$, with hypotenuse $BC$ draw the segment $CP$ which bisects angle $\hat{C}$ and denote with $Q$ the projection of $P$ onto $BC$. Show that: a) $AC=QC;$ b) $AQ \perp CP.$

What I have done:

For part (a) since $\hat{ACP}=\hat{PCQ}$ (because $CP$ bisects angle $\hat{C}$) and side $PC$ is shared by the triangle we have that the right triangles $\Delta\ CAP$ and $\Delta\ CPQ$ are congruent hence $AC=QC$, as desired.

I am having difficulties with part (b) since I cannot use analytic or vector geometry and I can't see how to do it with synthetic geometry so I would appreciate an hint about how to prove this second result, thanks.

[image: triangle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $R$ the point of intersection of $CP$ and $AQ$. Triangles $APC$ and $CPQ$ are congruent because they are both right and $\angle ACP=\angle PCQ$ and share the hypothenuse. Therefore $AC=CQ$. Next, observe that triangles $ACR$ and $CRQ$ are congruent, since they share two sides and the angle in between. Therefore $\angle CRA=\angle CRQ$ so they have to be right.